# How determine cluster assignment of each instances after clustering through weka-python-wrapper

Tags: python, weka

```
from weka.clusterers import Clusterer

clusterer = Clusterer(classname="weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans", options=["-N", "6"])
clusterer.build_clusterer(data)
```

this does the clustering

After this , I want to know the clustering assignment of each instance.How can we do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cluster_instance(Instance)` method to obtain the 0-based index of the cluster or the `distribution_for_instance(Instance)` method to obtain the cluster distribution:

```py
for inst in data:
    cl = clusterer.cluster_instance(inst)
    dist = clusterer.distribution_for_instance(inst)
    print("cluster=" + str(cl) + ", distribution=" + str(dist))
```